# nginx rewrite rule not applied (using contao cms)

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx, configuration

I am trying to make a redirect for `https://mypage.com/foo` to `https://mypage.com/bar` while still keeping `https://mypage.com/foo` in the browser url. I have tried several combinations of different rewrite flags, putting them into the location block etc., but nothing worked so far.

The target CMS ([Contao](https://contao.org)) uses `app.php` as an entry and pages can be requested like `/app.php/foo?param=value`. The rewrite rule when not using the permanent flag is not applied at all and the REQUEST_URI in `app.php` always outputs `foo`.

my config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    root /var/www/mypage/web;

    server_name mypage.com;

    include /mydir/redirect-old-links.conf; # contains permanent rewrite rules with hardcoded links

    rewrite ^(.*).html(\?.*)?$ $1 permanent; # redirect to remove .html suffix
    rewrite ^/foo /bar; # <--- This won't have an effect

    # ... ssl stuff

    location / {
        index app.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /\n";
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: A redirect changes the URL in the browser bar.  What you describe is a "rewrite".  You use the term "rewrite" a couple times correctly, but you should never refer to it as a redirect.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with nginx syntax.   Under Apache, leading slashes are often the problem depending on which file the rewrite is in.   Have you tried `rewrite ^foo bar`?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller No that didn't work, either.